# How do I find related lectures?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a web site that shows info about lectures that are available. Each lecture has a title, an associated speaker, and (potentially) multiple categories. The database schema looks something like this (warning: this is air-code, as I don't have the database in front of me)...

```
create table Lectures (
  ID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  Title varchar(max) not null default '',
  SpeakerID int not null foreign key references Speakers(ID)
)

create table Categories (
  ID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  Name varchar(max) not null default ''
)

create table Lectures_Categories (
  ID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  LectureID int not null foreign key references Lectures(ID),
  CategoryID int not null foreign key references Categories(ID)
)
```

When viewing details about a lecture, I would like to be able to recommend related lectures, but am not sure how to code this. My initial thought is that the following criteria would be used to calculate relevance (most important first)...

- Common categories - ie the more categories shared by the two lectures, the more likely they are to be related
- Similarity in title - ie the more words shared by the two lectures, the more likely they are to be related.
- Same speaker

If two lectures were equally ranked according to the above criteria, I would like to rank newer ones above older ones.

Anyone any idea how I would go about coding this? I'm doing this in C#, using an Entity Framework model against an SQL Server database if any of that is relevant.

Comment: Simply spy on users what they are doing (as windows 10 does). Store statistic and show lectures which users are visiting shortly after visiting specific one (as amazon does). With some filtering those are *related*.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, but that probably wouldn't work, as the users would likely be listening to the lecture, so would be on the web page for an hour or so. They might come back later, but they wouldn't have much of a continuous browsing history. I'm looking more for a way to find related lectures purely based on what's in the database.

Comment: I think one way is if you categorize the courses in your database in a correct way(vague e.g: Biology, Zoology, Theoretical physics, Applied Physics etc. catalogues) then if a course under a category is on play then you can pull other courses in that category. Also you can provide a link for speaker where if the user clicks then pull all the lectures delivered by him. Wouldn't that start easing your thought process?

Comment: Well that sounds like a straight forward thing; you already nailed it. Create the three sql selects and union the results..Not knowing your db structure makes it hard to get more detailed..

Comment: @SivaGopal Thanks for the reply, but if you look at my question, I explained that each lecture can be in multiple categories. We don't have courses here, each lecture is technically independent, but there are a set of about 15 categories that cover everything. Any one lecture could be in any number of categories. I want to know how I would go about ranking other lectures based on the number of matching categories, ie the more matches the better. Once I'd done that, I would then want to further rank them by matching words in the title, etc.

Comment: @TaW I added a database schema in case it helps. I don't see how three queries is going to help. I want to rank the other lectures based on three criteria. Three queries would give me three separate sets of results, with no way of knowing how to rank them.

Answer (score 1):

Let me sktech out the basic idea: Assuming all three criteria can be expressed in sql queries you should get **weighed** result sets which you then `union` together.

The first would simply be `select ID, 10 as weight from lectures where  ID <> ourLectureID and speakerID = ourSpeakerID`

The second will be a `join` over `Lectures` and `Topics` with a lesser weight, maybe `4`.

Let's ignore the problems with the 3rd query for now.

Now that we have a set `result1` of IDs and weights we do a group & sum. My sql is rather rusty today, but I'm thinking of something like this: `select max(ID), sum(weight) as ranking from result1 group by ID order by ranking`.. Done!

Now I haven't touched SQL server in almost 20 years ;-) but I think it is not well suited for creating the 3rd query. And the db designer will only give you the funny look and tell you that querying the Title is bad bad bad; and 'why didn't you add a `keywords` table..??

If you don't want to da that, as I assume you can pull all Titles into your C# application and use its string/collections/LINQ abilities to filter out interesting words and create the third query with a third ranking; maybe only capitalized words with 4 letters or more..?

**Update**

Here is a tiny example of how you can find a best fitting line among a list of lines:

```
List<string> proverbs = new List<string>();
List<string> cleanverbs = new List<string>();
List<string> noverbs = new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    noverbs.AddRange(new[] { "A", "a", "by", "of", "all", "the", "The", 
        "it's", "it", "in", "on", "is", "not", "will", "has", "can", "under" });

    proverbs = File.ReadLines("D:\\proverbs\\proverbs.txt").ToList();
    cleanverbs = proverbs.Select(x => cleanedLine(x)).ToList();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(proverbs.ToArray());
    listBox2.Items.AddRange(cleanverbs.ToArray());
}

string cleanedLine(string line)
{
    var words = line.Split(' ');
    return String.Join(" ", words.ToList().Except(noverbs) );
}

int countHits(string line, List<string> keys)
{
    var words = line.Split(' ').ToList();
    return keys.Count(x => words.Contains(x));
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int max = 0;
    foreach (string proverb in cleanverbs)
    {
        var keys = proverb.Split(' ').ToList();
        int count = countHits(line, keys);
        if (count > max && proverb != line)
        {
            max = count;
            Text = proverb + " has " + max + " hits";
        }
    }
}
```

It makes use of two listboxes and a text file of proverbs. When loaded you can click on the second listbox and the window title will display the line with the most hits.

You will want to make a few changes:

- pull your titles from your DB, including their keys
- create a more extensive and expandable file with non-verbs
- decide on mixed-case
- create not one result but an ordered set of lines
- maybe optimize a few things so you don't have to split the body of titles more than once

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you didn't read my question properly. My #1 rule for matching is common categories, and I am looking for a way of working out how to rank those. I know I need some sort of of join over the lectures and categories, but how do I do it? Please read the 1st bullet point in my question for what I want to do.

Comment: As for the 3rd query, we don't have a keywords table because this is a new requirement. Adding one wouldn't help unless we could populate it automatically from the titles (in which case we might as well just extract the keywords from the titles when we do the query), because the site admins would never bother adding keywords to the several thousand lectures already in there, and would probably forget to do it for new ones as well. If this is going to work, I would need to pull the keywords out of the titles when we search. That's why I was asking if anyone knew of a way to do this. Thx

Comment: I have added an example that shows the basic idea for processing the 3rd query. Do note that is very basic but it may get you started..

Comment: Thx I'll take a closer look at that